# Correct driver to connect to Cloudera VM 5.10(CDH 5.10) hue hive interface sample database from client interface

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue, cloudera-quickstart-vm, dbvisualizer

I am trying to make a connection to Cloudera VM 5.10(CDH 5.10) hue hive interface sample database to test the right driver using dbVisualizer tool (https://www.dbvis.com/download) 
I checked CDH 5.10 has hive version 1.1, I got this information from

I tested two drivers 
    1) Hive JDBC 1.1.0 standalone from 
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/1.1.0/
    2) "hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.10.0-standalone.jar" directly  getting from cdh VM.

```
Cunnection URL I am giving is :
jdbc:hive://http://127.0.0.1:10000


When I connect I get this error message 
"An error occurred while establishing the connection:
The selected Driver cannot handle the specified Database URL.
The most common reason for this error is that the database URL
contains a syntax error preventing the driver from accepting it.
The error also occurs when trying to connect to a database
with the wrong driver. Correct this and try again."
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Your connection URL is wrong. If you download the driver from Cloudera's website, you will also get a manual which describes how to create a jdbc connection to hive. You can also Google that.

Comment: I have not downloaded the driver as I don't know where can I download it from, I copied it from CDH VM 5.10. Also if you know the correct URL can you please suggest what's wrong in my url?

Comment: download the jar from [here](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/hive/jdbc/2-5-4.html). you'll get a documentation along with the JAR. Read it, try to implement it. Ask if you get stuck anywhere.

Comment: Check [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-ConnectionURLFormat)